# Is it possible to identify a DOM element as unique?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to identify a DOM element as unique via clicking on it and change it later via jquery replaceWith method?

Comment: the easiest way would to make use of `id="foobar"` from the docs ```id = name [CS]
This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.```  https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: but how is it for example with an DOM element, which has no "id=" ? for example a simple <a href=text.html> </a> ?

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  If you continue to ask poor quality and downvoted questions, you will get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to save an element as a variable?

Comment: yes thats what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the clicked element with the `target` property of an event object.

```js
addEventListener("click", event => {
    const element = event.target;
    console.log(element);
    // Now do whatever you like with the element 
});
```

```html
<button>a</button>
<button>b</button>
<button>c</button>
<button>d</button>
<button>e</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I now change for example the text for the button "c"?

Comment: @jochen6677 — That's a different question and, while you *could* [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), you'd been better off with an [introductory DOM tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).